# Is this "semi-tensor product" something recently invented? Are there other usages of it?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras, matrix-theory, tensor-products

**The context:** I was reading a paper in which they used the following definition called "Semi-Tensor Product" (STP) or "Cheng" product (In honor to its "inventor" D. Cheng):

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, B\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times t}$. Then,
the STP $\ltimes$ of $A,B$ is defined as:
$$ 
A\ltimes B = (A\otimes I_{r/n})(B\otimes I_{r/p}) 
$$
where $I_q\in\mathbb{R}^{q\times q}$ is the identity matrix, $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product and $r$ is the least common multiple of $n$ and $p$.

Note that this product allows matrices of any sizes (same as the Kronecker product), but  when $n=p$ the product complies $A\ltimes B = AB$ under usual matrix multiplication. Hence, this seems like a "nice" generalization of usual matrix multiplication.

Apparently, this product was first introduced in [this work](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02714570) by Cheng. This product seems to have some very nice properties (many not mentioned here). However, I can't find much literature or usages of this product outside Cheng's circle. Provided the very simple structure it has, I suspect that a similar or equivalent definition of this product may be found in other areas of math under a different name or notation.

**The question:** Do you recognize this product to be found/used in other areas or math, perhaps under a different name, or is this a truly recent definition?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer this question. Since the question focuses only on the originality, I answer mainly about originality.

You already found the most original paper, YES, Cheng is the one who invented this operator. And Cheng's recent work generalized this original STP, STP has more different versions now.

Cheng ever wrote down the story of the development. If you read Chinese, here is the story https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/626893082?utm_id=0. If you don't read Chinese, just throw the text into google translate. The story can convince you the originality of STP, by showing you where the idea was from and how the STP method grows. A similar story see Cheng's own blog https://blog.sciencenet.cn/blog-660333-529186.html (in Chinese).

The power of STP is to deal with multilinear algebra and any subjects related to it. STP is not the only method to deal with multilinear algebra, Cheng has been competing with other methods. After all these 20 year, the reviewers of the publications have already checked the originality for hundreds of times. You should believe the reviewers of the top mathematics journals.

You said you cannot "find much literature or usages of this product outside Cheng's circle". Although I don't know how you define the radius of the circle, this is not really true. STP has many different successful applications, including boolean network, game theory, automata, graph theory, control theory,biology,power systems ...... The authors are from more than 50 countries. Today, STP has already become a common tool to deal with multilinar subjests.

You ask if STP has an another name under a different author. To deny it rigorously, one needs to check too many publications, this is not easy even by the aid of search engines. Even if there is another independent equivalence, obviously he didn't not dig it deep enough and develope it deep enough as Cheng did.

Hope this could help.

Comment: Could you please sketch some of the applications?

Comment: STP deals with multilinear algebra, which is presented by hypermatrix. Basically, what STP is doing is to "pave" the hyper cubic matrix into a matrix, and investigate how to preserve the original properties. Then we can deal with (0,q) tensor or even (p,q) tensor, instead of (0,2) tensor only. The consequence of the transformation then leads to so called semi-tensor algebra. So theorecally, it deals with any multilinear subjests. I'll take boolean network for example. Cheng found that ANY multivariable logic function and be written into linear form Lx, by STP manipulation. This is amazing!

Comment: Based on this, his analysis of controllability and observability of boolean network result earned the best paper award of top journal Automatica. And further researches are still going on. Similar things also happen to game theory, and ... More examples see Cheng's blog I gave above, or go to Cheng's STP application papers or books. Welcome to the world of STP.

Comment: Frankly, this still sounds more like advertising rather then explanation. The whole idea of tensors is to convert polylinear maps into linear one, so what exactly is it that makes these semi-tensor product more convenient?

Comment: I'm not in Cheng's circle, I just like his work. I'm sorry if it looks like ad. It is convenient coz for a (0, 3) tensor, it is a cube matrix originally, not a matrx that you can put it down on a paper. With stp, you can pave it into a large matrix than can be put down on a paper. Then next, what can you do with this large matrix, can you multiply it with sth by normal matrix product? No, you cannot. You have to develop a new product law to make it make sense. It's lucky that such law exists. Then you can deal with (p,q) tensor with new linear algebra now.